# Running clang-format with command line: specify IncludeCategories

Tags: include-path, clang-format

I want to run [clang-format](http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormat.html) (version 3.8) with the command line. With the "-style=" option one can specify the ClangFormatStyleOptions. However, I was not able to find out how to specify the "IncludeCategories". In the [Documentation](http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) it is only described how to do it with a style configuration file.
So I was wondering, whether it is possible to specify it with the command line and if yes, how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is as follows:

```
-style="{IncludeCategories: [{Regex: 'bla', Priority: 100}, {Regex: 'blubb', Priority: 101}]}"
```

I found this through experimentation and cannot cite any sources.

---

I am using clang-format-6.0 and I observed the following unexpected behavior.
Say I start with some default style and use the `-dump-config` flag and get the follow `IncludeCategories`:

```
IncludeCategories: 
  - Regex:           '^<ext/.*\.h>'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
```

And then I add `IncludeCategories: [{Regex: 'bla', Priority: 100}]` to `-style` and dump the result of that, I get:

```
IncludeCategories: 
  - Regex:           'bla'
    Priority:        100
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
```

So it is overwriting entries of the default map, but it does not delete the map when the `IncludeCategories` is added to `-style`.  I had to overwrite it with dummy entries and then append my actual entries to get the desired result.

Comment: If it works, why would it need sources? Congratulations!

Comment: I tried to use this syntax to specify BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
    AfterClass: false
    AfterFunction: true

No luck so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71178542/how-to-specify-suboptions-for-clang-format