# How to specify suboptions for clang-format?

Tags: clang-format

In the .clang-format file I can say:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
    AfterClass: false
    AfterFunction: true
```

How do I specify the same on the command line? (For some reason using .clang-format is not an option.)

I tried:

```
--style="{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, BreakBeforeBraces: Custom, BraceWrapping:, AfterClass: false, AfterFunction: true}"
```

and

```
--style="{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, BreakBeforeBraces: Custom, BraceWrapping: AfterClass: false, BraceWrapping: AfterFunction: true}"
```

as well as some other variations using BraceWrapping.Afterclass, BraceWrapping:AfterClass, BraceWrappingAfterClass, etc.

I also tried:

```
--style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Custom, BraceWrapping: [{AfterClass: false}, {AfterFunction: true}]}"
```

which attempt was based on: [Running clang-format with command line: specify IncludeCategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190179/running-clang-format-with-command-line-specify-includecategories)

and some further variants of this. No luck so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further tries lead to:

```
--style="{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, BreakBeforeBraces: Custom, BraceWrapping: {AfterClass: false, AfterFunction: true}}"
```